# Error 1004 VB6 program filling Excel

Tags: excel, vb6, crash

I have a legacy software (Visual Basic 6) that fills an excel sheet.

It normally works. However, on a Win7 64 bit computer using Office 2013 I have an issue:

It works well if the lines aren't too many.
However after 418 lines it crashes with this error

> 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

On a Win XP 32 bit using Office 2007 it works well (I tested up to 512 lines).

It stops at the line:

```
myWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(Range) = rsttemp("FIELDNAME")
```

where Range = B420 when it crashes, and `rsttemp("FIELDNAME")` is a 12 char string.

It is in a loop and works correctly, so it should not be a syntax problem. I tried to clear the clipboard at beginning of every loop and it got to line 458
so I suspect a memory problem.

Comment: Is this on a particular workbook? Have you tested that workbook on both OS'? 418 is a bit specific. Maybe it's that one 418 line workbook that is causing you trouble and not the OS?

Comment: I read data from a database and create an Excel file. Same extraction (512 lines) on both OS. It Works on Windows Xp with office 2007. I get the crash on Windows 7 with Office 2013 only if there's too much data